# Why isn't my Hubot script running?

Tags: node.js, heroku, coffeescript, npm, hubot

My Coffeescript and npm experience is pretty limited, but I still can't for the life of me figure out what I'm doing wrong. I've forked GitHub's [Hubot](https://hubot.github.com), configured it, and launched it on Heroku tied in with our Slack account. Works great, no problems. I even forked an existing script, [hubot-pugme](https://github.com/hubot-scripts/hubot-pugme) into a [different script](https://github.com/amsoell/hubot-otterme) that I modified and installed, and that works great.

But now I'm running into a problem on my next script; It's intended to take a standard command, look up an XML feed, parse through it and return some of the results. It works fine from the command line, and also when run on my local machine, but when I publish up to Heroku I don't get any errors, but the trigger also doesn't do anything.

My best guess as to what is wrong is that I'm somehow indicating the one dependency, [xml2jx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2js) incorrectly, so Heroku isn't building it in. If someone familiar with building scripts for Hubot has a minute to look at what I have here, I would appreciate it. Full code for my script is at https://github.com/amsoell/hubot-nowplaying

Comment: Did you manage to get this working?

Comment: @GabLeRoux I did, by adding the xml2js dependency to hubot itself. I still have no idea why listing the script as a dependency of hubot, and xml2js as a dependency of the script, it didn't cascade and install xml2js in the process, but things are working and I'm leaving well enough alone for now.